# Is there any Matlab toolbox for neural network that can run on GPU?

Tags: matlab, cuda, neural-network, gpu

I tried with GPUmat, but the neural network toolbox from mathworks does´t support it. Otherwise I must change the nn-toolbox by myself. But it´s too hard for me. Any suggestion for me?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether this will accelerate the Neural Network Toolbox in particular, but the Mathworks now offers CUDA GPU support via the Parallel Computing Toolbox:

http://www.mathworks.com/discovery/matlab-gpu.html?s_cid=HP_MI_tech_gpu

Answer (score 1):

Matlab provides its own toolbox for training neural networks on GPU, see [here](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/nnet/ug/neural-networks-with-parallel-and-gpu-computing.html).
As an author, I also advice to use my toolbox [ConvNet](http://github.com/sdemyanov/ConvNet), that uses kernels of Alex Krizhevsky's library [cuda-convnet2](https://code.google.com/p/cuda-convnet2/). It also has pure CPU and Matlab versions, that work identically. There is also another toolbox for Matlab, called [MatConvNet](http://www.vlfeat.org/matconvnet/), but I have not checked it.